# Loop through multiple forms data

Tags: vb.net

The following code allows me to save textbox & combobox data to a file....

```
    sw = New StreamWriter(fname, False)
    For i As Integer = 1 To 9
        Dim tb = DirectCast(t3frm.Controls("TextBoxLo" & i), TextBox)
        Dim cb = DirectCast(t3frm.Controls("comboboxlo" & i), ComboBox)
        sw.WriteLine(tb.Text)
        sw.WriteLine(Val(cb.SelectedIndex))
    Next

    For i As Integer = 1 To 3
        Dim tb = DirectCast(t3frm.Controls("textboxhi" & i), TextBox)
        Dim cb = DirectCast(t3frm.Controls("comboboxhi" & i), ComboBox)
        sw.WriteLine(tb.Text)
        sw.WriteLine(Val(cb.selectedindex))
    Next

    sw.Close()
    Me.Close()
```

Which works BUT i have 11 forms (t3frm to t13frm).
Is there a way of putting this code inside a loop instead of repeating the code 11 times ?
Thanks.

Comment: Make an array of forms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you make this a method where the form is passed in as a parameter you won't have to repeat this code:

```
Public Class SomeSharedClass

    Public Sub DoWork(ByVal frmTarget As Form)

        sw = New StreamWriter(fname, False)
        For i As Integer = 1 To 9
            Dim tb = DirectCast(frmTarget.Controls("TextBoxLo" & i), TextBox)
            Dim cb = DirectCast(frmTarget.Controls("comboboxlo" & i), ComboBox)
            sw.WriteLine(tb.Text)
            sw.WriteLine(Val(cb.SelectedIndex))
        Next

        For i As Integer = 1 To 3
            Dim tb = DirectCast(frmTarget.Controls("textboxhi" & i), TextBox)
            Dim cb = DirectCast(frmTarget.Controls("comboboxhi" & i), ComboBox)
            sw.WriteLine(tb.Text)
            sw.WriteLine(Val(cb.selectedindex))
        Next

        sw.Close()
        'Me.Close()
        'frmTarget.Close()?

    End Sub 

End Class
```

Then call it from the form like this:

```
Dim objSharedClass As New SomeSharedClass()

objSharedClass.DoWork(Me)
```

Or if you are at a spot where you have access to all the forms you wish to run it for:

```
objSharedClass.DoWork(t3frm)
objSharedClass.DoWork(t4frm)
objSharedClass.DoWork(t5frm)
'Etc
```

If you need all of the contents in the single StreamWriter you can pass that in too:

```
Public Function DoWork(ByVal frmTarget As Form, ByVal sw As StreamWriter) As StreamWriter

    'Don't initialize or close the StreamWriter here anymore!  Do the other code though.

    Return sw

End Function
```

And then usage:

```
sw = New StreamWriter(fname, False)
sw = objSharedClass.DoWork(t3frm, sw)
sw = objSharedClass.DoWork(t4frm, sw)
'etc
sw.Close()
```

Comment: Using a method did exactly what i wanted. thank you !